# Understanding git revert and git merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I just made a very big git blunder which made me realize that I don't understand Git.
Here's what happened -

1. Made a private branch from master, made changes in that branch
2. Pulled master into that branch.
3. Switched to the master branch (didn't pull from origin/master and hence my master branch didn't have the latest master)
4. Merged my private branch and pushed it to master.
5. Got an error saying that you can't push  without pulling to which I complied and pulled the master. And then pushed it along with my commits.
6. In my commit all the changes that I pulled from master into my private branch and were not in my local master were there.
7. Reverted the commit, the revert reverted all those changes that I didn't make and the commit history is gone for all those changes.

I don't understand why the commit history of individual files are gone. Can someone help me understand this?

P.S. Lesson learnt - Always pull before push and pull often

Comment: Revert does not destroy history and reverts only commits from arguments. Consider resetting your master to the state before revert and reverting proper commits this time.

Comment: @Basilevs The commit history is there but if individual file commit history is lost.  I was also under the impression that commit history should not be destroyed but don't know why commits history of files are lost.

Answer (score 0):

> Reverted the commit, the revert reverted all those changes that I didn't make and the commit history is gone for all those changes.

The commit history should still be part of that branch (`git log`), or at least be in the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).
A [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) is supposed to create a new commit (whose content cancel an older one) on top of existing commit.

Once you have found the right commit, ie. the one before you started merging and reverting in your private branch, reset said private branch to it (`git reset --hard`: make sure you don't have any local modifications or do a git stash first)

Then try again, this time updating master first (git pull)

Answer (score 0):

When we do a `git merge` or a `git pull`, which is almost equal to `git fetch and git merge`, there are 2 kinds of successful results, either a fast-forward(ff) merge or a non-fast-forward(no-ff) merge is made. Reference: [git-merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). Please take a look at 'FAST-FORWARD MERGE' and 'TRUE MERGE'.

Some remote repositories may have a strategy to refuse to accept any push that is to result in a non-ff merge. It's better to always make sure your local branch is a proper superset of the remote branch right before you are going to push.

Here a proper superset, or a strict superset, along with a proper subset,  means what it is in mathematics.

If Branch Master is like `A-B-C-D`, and Branch Priavate is like `A-B-C-D-E-F`, we can say Master is a proper subset of Private. To pull from Private to Master, or push Private to Master, or merge Private into Master, will make a fast-forward merge. If we pull from Master to Private, or push from Master to Private, or merge Master into Private, nothing will happen except telling you everything-up-to-date.

If Branch Private is like `A-B-C-E`, Master is not a subset of Private and vice versa. Pull, push, merge will all lead to a non-fast-forward merge.

Here's what I am doing in my daily work:

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout -b master FETCH_HEAD
#change the code
git add .
git commit
#right before I am going to `git push`
git fetch origin master
git cherry HEAD FETCH_HEAD
#if there is any new commit in the remote master, `git cherry` will list it.
#if `git cherry` outputs nothing, which means the local master is a
#superset of the remote master, my `git push` will make a 
#fast-forward merge.
git push origin master:master
...
#else if `git cherry` outputs something, like `+ 12345667800abcdef`, 
#which measn someone else has updated the remote master, 
#my `git push` will make a non-fast-forward merge.
#suppose the local master is like `A-B-C-D` and the remote master is like `A-B-C-E-F`
git reset C --hard
git pull origin master
git cherry-pick D
#now the local master is like `A-B-C-E-F-D'`, which is now a proper 
#superset of the remote master
git push origin master:master
```